# .NET Core - System.Private.CoreLib.dll vs System.Runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, xml-documentation

In a .NET Core App, if I do

`typeof(DateTime).Assembly.Location`

I get

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.4\System.Private.CoreLib.dll

But the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netcore-3.1) for the DateTime struct says the assembly is `System.Runtime.dll`

I am trying to locate the XML Documentation file for `DateTime`. I cannot locate a `System.Private.CoreLib.xml` on my system but a `System.Runtime.xml` does accompany the `System.Runtime.dll` file in its folder (per XML documentation convention).

How does `System.Private.CoreLib.dll` relate to `System.Runtime.dll` ?

I am trying to use Roslyn to grab the XML `<Summary>` tag content, (similar to a hover tooltip in Visual Studio) but I cant see how to associate a Type with the location of the XML documentation ?

Comment: Doesn't Roslyn already handle this for you?

Comment: Not that I can see from any of the information I have read. It seems like the XML document resolution is still manual.

Comment: I did some digging. See if `CompletionItem.Description` from `CompletionService` is of any help.

Comment: Appreciate the digging. `CompletionItem.InlineDescription` is always blank. I get the feeling this is for another purpose. I also checked `CompletionService.GetDescription()` but it returns `DateTime DateTime.Add(TimeSpan value)` as an example.

Comment: I can actually get the description via Roslyn, the problem is I need to resolve and supply the path to the XML documentation file, roslyn does not do this internally.

Comment: System.Private.CoreLib.dll documentation is mscorlib.xml.    System.Runtime.dll documentation is System.Runtime.xml.   System.Runtime.dll is a reference assembly and references System.Private.CoreLib.dll so, they both share many types in common.   XML-documentation of the same types are in these 2 XML files and sometimes they are different.

Answer (score 6):

> How does `System.Private.CoreLib.dll` relate to `System.Runtime.dll` ?

`System.Runtime.dll` is a so-called *[Reference assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies)*, which means it's only containing the public API without implementation:

> Reference assemblies are a special type of assembly that contain only the minimum amount of metadata required to represent the library's public API surface.

For the actual implementation it's forwarding to other assemblies, the so-called *implementation assemblies*.
One of these implementation assemblies is `System.Private.CoreLib.dll`.

Comment: Is there a way to determine that relationship using reflection, so the correct xml documentation file can be loaded ?